# how to use Jni Api from dart in flutter app

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to use the JniApi as described in this link in [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/326)

but the import `'dart: jni';` shows error.

I just want to get the current application context and show a toast message in flutter app.

Please can someone help me to use this library and wanted to know if this API works in iOS as well (if the app is deployed on iPhone).

Many Thanks,
Mahi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the `dart:jni` was added to flutter on request and was removed as flutter found other alternatives. [Here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9129) is the issue that tracks the removal of `dart:jni` and [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/4728) is a few discussion of removal.

Hope that helped!

Comment: Oh thanks hemanth I never realised this. Thank you for your help.